# How to calculate this probability of the stochastic process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Find the value of $F_{X_{1/6},X_1}(0,1/4)$
Where $X_t=U\cos(\pi t)$, U is uniform $(-1,1)$.

My answer is $$F_{X_{1/6},X_1}(0,1/4)=P(U\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\leq 0, U\cos(\pi)\leq 1/4)\\\qquad\quad=P(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}U\leq 0,-U\leq 1/4)\\\qquad\quad=P(U\leq 0,U\geq -1/4)=P(-1/4\leq U\leq0)\\\qquad\quad=P(-1/4\leq U\leq 0)=1/8$$

Is that correct?

Comment: How'd you get from that second-to-last step to the last step?

Comment: Check the text again, I have added a step.

Comment: Yes, it is correct :-)

Comment: It is correct.  At first, I thought the $U$ was $U_t$ (i.e., redrawn i.i.d. at each $t$), but given a fixed $U$ for all $t$, your answer is correct.